# How find from different multiple criteria in mongodb

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb

I have  a collection with different entries like this

```
foods{
{ 
  name: 'rice'
  type: 'Brazilian'
},
{
  name: 'meat'
  type: 'Spanish'
}
,
{
  name: 'Cake'
  type: 'Brazilian'
}
```

How do I select an  get  a specific amount foods  of each type of food
for example it should return a collection(array)  of 4 foods for each type in mongodb

```
[
    [
        {
            name: 'rice'
            type: 'Brazilian'
        },
        {
            name: 'meat'
            type: 'Brazilian'
        }       
        {
            name: 'pizza'
            type: 'Brazilian'
        },
        {
            name: 'bread'
            type: 'Brazilian'
        }
    ],

    [
        {
            name: 'beans'
            type: 'spanish'
        },
        {
            name: 'fish'
            type: 'spanish'
        }       
        {
            name: 'chocolare'
            type: 'spanish'
        },
        {
            name: 'ham'
            type: 'spanish'
        }
    ]

]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use aggregation to get the desired result. In your aggregation pipeline, the **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** operator takes center stage in creating the desired result since you can group the documents from the collection getting into the pipeline by the type key. Once grouped then you can use one of the accumulator operators **[`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/#grp._S_push)** to create the array. Something like the following:

```
var pipeline = [
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$type",
            "docs": {
                "$push": { "name": "$name", "type": "$type" }
            }
        }
    }
]

var result = db.foods.aggregate(pipeline).map(function (doc){ return doc.docs });
printjson(result);
```